# Angular 7 injecting directive as provider

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a directive which is listening for wheel events in which I do some logic with the delta and change the class in the compnent accordingly.

The problem comes when I inject it, at one of the components it works, but in the second component it reads only the initial value and then the value is not updated when it is updated in the wheel directive:

Wheel directive

```
@Directive({ selector: '[mouseWheel]' })
export class MouseWheelDirective implements OnInit {
  profileAnimation = {
    animate : false
  }

  @HostListener('wheel', ['$event']) 
  Wheel(e) {
     if(delta < 180){
         this.profileAnimation.animate = true
     }
  }
```

in my component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-create',
  templateUrl: './create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create.component.css']
})
export class CreateComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private wheelDirective : MouseWheelDirective) {
  }
}
```

and in the html:

```
<div mouseWheel>
    <div [ngClass]="{'fade-in' : this.wheelDirective.profileAnimation.animate'}"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Also i include it in the providers:

```
  providers: [
    MouseWheelDirective
  ],
```

I don't understand why it works in one of my component but the value is not dinamic when I use it in the other component. Is this because I am not supposed to use @Directive as injectable provider?

Also I tried to use a service which I inject in both the directive and the component to use it as a link between both and it works, but it doesn't feel right. Is there a better approach?

Comment: Constructor injection is for accessing providers from the parent context. The HTML example you gave looks like it is from `create.component.html`? If that is true, then you need to use `@ViewChild(MouseWheelDirective)` instead.

Comment: @Reactgular thanks that worked. Does this also apply for the services that are listed in providers and with @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
}) or only when it is a directive used in the html?